# ‘Would’ and ‘will’ in a same sentence

Tags: grammar, modal-verbs

“The smaller the friend circle ‘would’ be, the cozier it ‘will’ get.”

Is the ‘will’ in the second clause correct here or should we say ‘would’ like the first clause to balance?

Answer (score 1):

Neither half works for me.

Not counter-factual:

> The smaller the friend circle gets to be/becomes, the cosier it **will** get.

Counter-factual:

> The smaller the friend circle got to be/became/were to be, the cosier it **would** get.

I am aware that some American speakers use *would* in counter-factual conditional ("If it would happen ... ") and I guess that those speakers could use *would be* in the counter-factual case here, but it sounds strange to me.

Answer (score 0):

**will** is correct here. The first half is a *hypothetic situation*, hence **would** makes more sense there.